# Extracting year from date column using Panda

Tags: python

So I have a CSV containing a bunch of columns, `Date` being one of them, which I'm mostly interested in right now. I've managed to extract the column from the file, but I'm not interested in the entire date, only the 'year' part of it.

```
with open("/Users/thomasjn/Documents/sfpd_incidents.csv", 'r') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)

    dates = data['Date'].str.split('/')
```

This is what I've done so far, which gives me a result like this:

```
0          [01, 19, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
1          [02, 01, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
2          [02, 01, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
3          [02, 01, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
4          [01, 27, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
5          [02, 01, 2015 12:00:00 AM]
```

But how do I remove everything from the date except the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) to transform your `Series`:

```
dates=dates.apply(lambda x: x[2])
```

This will give you only the third element of every list, which is the year you wanted.